# LocalStorage Get Item with Dot/Bracket Notation Not Working with JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage, stringify

**If possible, I would like to be able to use shorthand notation to get an item from `localStorage` and then use `JSON.parse()` on it.**

In my code below, if I use the following it works:

```
var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('testObject')); //works
```

However, if I use one of the two following shorthand options, it doesn't work:

```
var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.testObject); //doesn't work

var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage['testObject']); //doesn't work
```

**All of my code is below and on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TestB/1/.**

```
//var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('testObject')); //works
var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.testObject); //doesn't work
//var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage['testObject']); //doesn't work

if (retrievedObject == null) {

  var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };

  // Put the object into storage
  localStorage.testObject = JSON.stringify(testObject);

}

else {

 retrievedObject.four = 4;

 // Put the object into storage
 localStorage.testObject = JSON.stringify(retrievedObject);

}
// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('testObject'));

console.log('retrievedObject: ', retrievedObject);​
```

Comment: Works fine for me here: First run: `retrievedObject:  
Object
one: 1
three: 3
two: 2`  Second run: `four: 4
one: 1
three: 3
two: 2`

Comment: For me too... I also made sure to edit the retrieving line in the bottom to `['testObject']` and `.testObject`

Comment: The jsFiddle didn't have the working code commented out. I've updated the question with an updated jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/TestB/1/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs the first time, when the `localStorage.testObject` is not yet defined..

In that case `localStorage.testObject` is undefined and `JSON.parse` fails with that argument

On the other hand the `getItem` method handles this internally and returns `null`..

You could use `JSON.parse(localStorage.testObject || null)`

Comment: Thanks! This works! Just so I understand...is the last options stating if `localStorage.testObject` doesn't exist then run `JSON.parse(null)`, which returns `null`?

Comment: @Mark yes.. `||` is the logical `OR` and we are using it as a [short-circuit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation). So if `localStorage.testObject` is `undefined` then it will use `null`.

Comment: @Mark `localStorage.testObject || null` returns the first truthy value in this expression or `null`, so if `localStorage.testObject` yields `undefined` you get `null` which happens to be returned when you access localStorage like you should: via `getItem()`!

Comment: @Christoph Why do you say "like you should" about using `getItem()`. Is the other wrong or in some way inferior?

Comment: @mark The getter and setter provide a consistent, standardised and crossbrowser compatible way to work with the LS api and should always be preferred over the other ways.