# Is there a difference between localStorage.getItem('foo') and localStorage['foo']

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is localStorage.getItem(‘item’) better than localStorage.item or localStorage[‘item’]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632463/is-localstorage-getitemitem-better-than-localstorage-item-or-localstoragei)

While learning about localStorage, I noted that it was possible to set and retrieve values from localStorage using array-accessor notation. I haven't been able to find anything super conclusive on whether it is bad or acceptable practice to use localStorage in this manner.

```
var foo = localStorage.getItem('Foo');
```

OR

```
var foo = localStorage['Foo'];
```

Similarly,

```
localStorage.setItem('Foo', foo);
```

OR

```
localStorage['Foo'] = foo;
```

Any gotchas? Or am I free to use the shorter syntax?