# LocalStorage Json String Retrieve

Tags: javascript, json

Morning,

I have wrote a function to fetch the data from json and return the value back, but its saying     SyntaxError: Unexpected token u

[image]
**Second Function**

```
   function fetchData(u, c, k) {
       return JSON.parse(localStorage[u + c][k]);
    }
```

**Logging**

```
console.log(fetchData(username, centre, "date"));
```

**Error**
Uncaught

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
function fetchData(u, c, k) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(u + c))[k];
}
```

Comment: This might be useful, difference between getItem and direct property access: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632463/is-localstorage-getitemitem-better-than-localstorage-item-or-localstoragei

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 function fetchData(u, c, k) {
       return JSON.parse(localStorage[u + c])[k];
    }
```