# Reloading the page through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reload a page only 1 time when the user goes to that page.

I am using the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (i = 1 ; i <= 1 ; i++) {
    location.reload();
    }
});
```

But it keeps on reloading the page. Any error with the for loop?

Comment: yeah - the error is, that if you reload yourself, the script also gets reloaded and therefore restarts!
you have to wrap something around your page, that loads the content.

Comment: Check for any persistent data client side as cookie or local/session storage. That's said, sounds really like a xy problem. Why would you need to reload page and especially in a `for` loop??? Doesn't make any sense

Comment: If you reload your page the `$(document).ready` is loaded again.

Comment: I want to reload the page only one time when the user goes to that page.

Comment: @Paramasivan **AND WHY** would you need that???

Comment: I have made some changes to html form action script. Users get old action file.

Comment: @Paramasivan You'd have better to ask question regarding this ↑ ↑ ↑ instead of the workaround you think would fix it: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript resets ***every*** time the page is loaded. Once the page is reloaded, your `for` loop is history. Here's an alternative using [HTML5 Local Storage](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('reload') != false)
        localStorage.setItem('reload', false);
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Comment: This will only work the first time you visit the page.  If you go back to the site later then it won't reload the page.

Comment: @Archer The OP hasn't explained it very well, but I think that is the requirement

Comment: @Archer If the OP is using a login system, they could `.removeItem` a `sessionStorage` on logout. This would most likely be the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need somehow make page remember that it's has already been loaded before. I would use localStorage/sessionStorage:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (!localStorage.reloaded) {
        location.reload();
        localStorage.reloaded = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Someone's being very harsh with their downvotes today. Btw, I **did not** realise we could use dot/bracket notation with `localStorage`. I'll consider that my something new for today, thanks!

Comment: @RGraham Yes, it's a little bit more concise then `getItem`. You can also use bracket notation like like with ordinary object.

Comment: You'd have better to set localStorage property before calling `reload()` method for better cross browser support. ***As a side note regarding setting property of localstorage vs using relevant method:*** http://stackoverflow.com/a/15439059/1414562

Comment: @A.Wolff Sure, I'm aware about differences between `getItem` and property access. Just in case of checks for falsy values it doesn't matter.

Comment: @dfsq Ya it doesn't really matter

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you'll need some mechanism of maintaining some kind of flag to indicate that the page has been reloaded that persists after reloading.

Common solutions to this would be cookies, url fragments, local storage.

**Cookie**

```
if(!(/\breloaded=1/.test(document.cookie))){
    document.cookie = 'reloaded=1';
    location.reload();
}
```

**URL fragment**

```
if(location.hash != '#reloaded'){
    location.hash = '#reloaded';
    location.reload();
}
```

**Local Storage**

```
if (localStorage.getItem('reloaded') != false) {
    localStorage.setItem('reloaded', false);
    location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set a cookie to be set using jquery when you first load the page and then use an if statement to run the reload if the page hasn't already been reloaded (which will be defined in the cookie) and delete the cookie after.