# Displaying Array Values From Local Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

I am trying to display the values that have been stored in an array within local storage. I have been able to store the values in local storage and add other values on the click of a button but I cant retrieve the values back out and display them on a page.

This is my code that adds values to local storage.

```
$("#player1Link").click(function() {

            if (localStorage.getItem("player1Favourite") !== null) {
                var a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('player1Favourite'));
                if (a.indexOf(chosenPlayerId) === -1) {
                    a.push(chosenPlayerId);
                    localStorage.setItem('player1Favourite', JSON.stringify(a));
                    alert("Pushed in");
                } else {
                    alert("Already in favourites");
                }
            } else {
                var a = [];
                a.push(chosenPlayerId);
                localStorage.setItem('player1Favourite', JSON.stringify(a));
            }
        })
```

I want to be able to click a button to retrieve the values and display them on the page but I can figure out the code to go in this function.
     `$("#playerRetrieve").click(function() {});`
If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a jsfiddle, it seems to work there: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhyp9Lww/)

try:

```
localStorage.getItem('player1Favourite');
```

or:

```
localStorage.player1Favourite
```

You might want to have a look at:
[this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632463/is-localstorage-getitemitem-better-than-localstorage-item-or-localstoragei)
or at 
[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure I understand you correctly, because if you just want to retrieve the values you can use the same code, just remove the insertion from your code and change the jQuery selector.

```
$("#playerRetrieve").click(function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("player1Favourite") !== null) {
        var a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('player1Favourite'));
        // Do what you want with the values, which are now in a.
    }
});
```