# LocalStorage - check if key exists

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between:

```
if (localStorage.regionCode) { }
```

AND

```
if (localStorage.getItem('regionCode') !== null) { }
```

Comment: Did you mean to put `=== null` or `!== null`?

Comment: @ajc2000 yes my bad...i updated the question

Comment: @Surreal It will, actually.

Comment: Oh cool, I'll have to start short-handing that

Comment: The first will also "say" there is no `regionCode` if `regionCode` contains an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript you have **truthy** and **falsey**. This means that every condition converts in an condition-statement to a boolean and represents `true` or `false`.

### Explenation

If `localStorage.regionCode` is an empty string `if(localStorage.regionCode)` would converts to `false` otherwise `true`.

---

For more details you could read the [blog post](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/) about truthy and falsey

Comment: The Storage API only stores strings: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Comment: @Andreas thanks for your note.

Answer (score 0):

In first case it is checking if there exist any storage item with name `regionCode`. In this case it will be `undefined` if there is no key by name `regionCode` in `localStorage` & in second case it is checking the value of the `localStorage` key `regionCode` which will return null.

See the information listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632463/is-localstorage-getitemitem-better-than-localstorage-item-or-localstoragei).

Answer (score 0):

`!== null` condition will be always fulfilled if only `regionCode` prop exists.

Similar situation with `localStorage.regionCode` with a slight difference, that it won't pass if `regionCode` is an empty string.