# Difference between localStorage.getItem('item') vs localStorage.item?

Tags: javascript

What is difference between
`localStorage.getItem('item')` 
vs
`localStorage.item`
is there any performance difference between those two method of accessing item in localStorage?

Is accessing item in localStorage like this: var i = localStorage.item faster than getItem function call?

Comment: no difference, if you are not using keys like `getItem`, `setItem`, and other that exist on localStorage

Comment: [Is localStorage.getItem('item') better than localStorage.item or localStorage\['item'\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12632463)

Comment: @Andrei so if there is no difference then why i should use long getitem('i') version over .i?

Comment: @GuramiNikolaishvili Who said you should? Read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/75841681/254343) substantiated _by the [HTML] standard_, don't go by opinions. "Programming by Stack Overflow" is part to blame for why so many Web pages, some of which once had changed hands for a lot of money, are so broken today. For a good reason we have _standard committees_ today, working out standards that _specify_ how the Web browser is to behave, so as to prevent people from getting their facts wrong, letting them instead get information from the proper source, and program accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The [HTML Standard specifies](http://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#dom-storage-getitem) the `getItem` method as follows:

> 1. If `this`'s `map[key]` does not exist, then return null.
> 2. Return `this`'s `map[key]`.

Further down from [the `Storage` interface definition](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-storage-interface), there is the following that explains what this `map` is:

> A Storage object has an associated:
>
> map
>
> A [storage proxy map.](http://storage.spec.whatwg.org/#storage-proxy-map)

And then this:

> The [supported property names](http://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#dfn-supported-property-names) on a Storage object storage are the result of running [get the keys](http://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#map-getting-the-keys) on storage's [map](http://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#concept-storage-map).

This at least confirms that using both `getItem` and property access boils down to accessing the map to obtain the value corresponding to the key -- meaning both `getItem` method and property access indeed use the same procedure so obtain the same value for a given key.

This is also alluded to from the [non-normative] note closer to the `Storage` interface specification, titled "For web developers":

> value = storage.getItem (key)
> value = storage[key]
>
> Returns the current value associated with the given key, or null if the given key does not exist.

The "HTML Standard" I quoted from, is linked from [the Mozilla Developer Network page on `Storage` class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage), among other places, which itself is discoverable through a Google search for `localStorage`. I recommend you bookmark the [Mozilla Developer Network](http://developer.mozilla.org) site and add it as a search engine so you can quickly discover relevant and important information on the Web APIs you use. Don't take MDN for granted though -- if in doubt or as habit, find the relevant standard they attempt to explain, and see if you can read the actual specification, to clear all doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think, there is a reason for which you should use one and not another.

There are some small differences, like `localStorage.getItem('item')` returns `null` when item doesn't exists, while `localStorage.item` returns  `undefined`, Obviously they are not the same at all, but javascript considers both of them as falsy. So i guess it does not really make that much of a difference.

You could use both, but the recommendation is to use function and below is why

The difference consists in a fact that `getItem()` and `setItem()` do not create any kind of conflict with the keys that currently exists in localStorage. In other words you can do something like below and it will work

```
// will not overwrite getItem() function
localStorage.setItem('getItem', 'getItem')

// will not return getItem function
// instead will return a string 'getItem' that is a value corresponding to key [getItem]
localStorage.getItem('getItem')
```

On the other hand using direct access to property if you write something like below, you will mess up things...

```
//will return getItem() function
localStorage.getItem            

// will overwrite getItem() function
localStorage.getItem = 'whatever'
```

Answer (score -1):

there is nothing regarding with `localStorage.item` its always `localStorage.getItem('itemname')` & `localStorage.setItem('itemname' , value)` & localStorage.clear()

Comment: Why i should use localStorage.getItem('itemname') over localStorage.itemname?

Comment: You can use there is nothing like localStorage.itemname